# Get a superlist of different lists in C++

Tags: c++

In C++ I want to create a `std::set<int>` superlist that inside store in each "box" a `std::set<int>` list, I guess the superlist will have to be a list of pointers to the first int of each list. Something like:

`superlist.insert(*list);`

How can I insert the list to the superlist, knowing that the lists type has to be set?

I am really bad with pointers and couldn't manage to solver it yet. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your question? Ideally, you should use std::shared_ptr<list> instead of list* (and not bother with deleting anything explicitly) but either way, to get answers, you will have to ask a concrete question first.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to store? Are you sure you don't want a vector of sets instead of a set of sets?

Comment: Why don't you post an example of what you accomplished so far?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Please give an example of what you want the data to look like.

Comment: Do you mean a std::list<std::list<int> > ?

Comment: Salgar, I guess I do not mind about having a vector of sets, I just need to store those lists so after introduce all of them I can have access to them in the easiest possible way.

Comment: Do you want one set which contains every int, or do you want a list of sets?

Comment: A list of sets. I am trying to cluster one database, and I have many clusters(just lists of integer) but I want to store them all in a set to have access to all of the clusters.

Comment: You just contradicted yourself. Please could you give an example of your ideal output.

Comment: Everytime I create a cluster(list of integers) I need to save it somewhere, because then, I will create another one. At the end I need to have all of them store.

Comment: My ideal output would be any c++ structure that have store every list of integers(clusters)

Comment: I think you should have a look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list . Then in the upper part of those site is a small section what they do. Because you use them interchangeably. Notice you can embed a list in a set and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need pointers for this. Just use a `std::vector`

```
std::set<int> my_set;
... insert things in the set ...
std::vector<std::set<int> > list_of_sets;
list_of_sets.push_back(my_set);
```

This will cause the set to be copied but unless you have billions of integers, or this is being done millions of times, it won't matter much.

Alternatively, you can insert the set into the vector and then use that element in the vector for your insertions directly, in which case you won't incur the copy cost. But I'm not sure how the rest of your code is laid out.

Perhaps what you want instead is a [Superset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset). In which case you should do this:

```
std::set<int> superset;

for each smaller set:
superset.insert(each_set.begin(), each_set.end());
```

Comment: Read @hetepeperfan's comment on the OP, I suggest reading the difference between a list, a set, and a vector and how they are fundamentally different

Comment: In both cases the program is returning me segmentation fault, but if I don't insert anything it runs ok. What could be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Who Knows, perhaps update the OP with some code...